# Determine indices of adjacent duplicate array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Hey I am new to asking questions here so I hope I do it right.  I am trying to figure out how to take an array of numbers (unsorted as I need their original index) and find any elements that are same, but the only ones I care about are the elements in the array that are the same, that are next to each other. In all instances, this will only happen one time. So any other duplicates, regardless of their value, they are meaningless. I only need the duplicates next to each other in the array.

The second part of my question is once I have located the duplicates in the array that are next to each other, I need to find out the index of that pair.

```
function yArrayDiff(yLandingZone, n) {
    let toFindDuplicates = totalY => totalY.filter((item, index) => totalY.indexOf(item) !== index)
    yLandingZone = toFindDuplicates(totalY);
    // if ()
    return yLandingZone;
};
```

This gives me my duplicates, but I am unable to find a way to modify it to do what I need it to.

Comment: If the input is `[ 6, 6 ]` should the output be `[ 0 ]`, or `[ 0, 1 ]`?

Comment: here is an example input ` [1000, 1500, 1400, 2100, 2100, 200,  500,  300,  200, 1000, 500, 800,  200,  800,  600, 1200,  900,  500,  300,  500] ` The only elements that I care about are at `[3]` and `[4]` There are multiple elements that are the same, however this pair is adjacent to each other. I need to know how to find the index of that pair. As my code shows above, I can find all the elements that are the same, however I need to keep the total array unsorted and find the index of these two elements.

Comment: And what is the desired output?

Comment: A more important input/output case is when the input is `[ 7, 7, 7 ]` - I could imagine an argument for the output to be any of `[ 0 ]`, `[ 0, 1 ]`, `[ 0, 1, 2 ]`, and even `[ 0, 1, 1, 2 ]` - I think we need a more rigorous definition for this problem.

Comment: In this instance I will never yield an input where this example of 3 numbers occurring simultaneously would make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generator solution:

```
let getAdjacentDupIndices = function*(arr) {
  // Yields every index `n` in `arr` such that either arr[n] === arr[n + 1],
  // or arr[n] === arr[n - 1]
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) if (arr[i] === arr[i - 1]) { yield i - 1; yield i; }
};
```

In action:

```js
let getAdjacentDupIndices = function*(arr) {
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) if (arr[i] === arr[i - 1]) { yield i - 1; yield i; }
};

let tests = [
  [ 0 ],
  [ 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1 ],
  [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ],
  [ 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ],
  [ 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5 ],
  [ 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3 ],
  [ 1000, 1500, 1400, 2100, 2100, 200, 500, 300, 200, 1000, 500, 800, 200, 800, 600, 1200, 900, 500, 300, 500 ]
];

for (let arr of tests) {
  console.log(`Adjacent inds for [ ${arr.join(', ')} ]:`);
  
  let has = false;
  for (let ind of getAdjacentDupIndices(arr)) {
    has = true;
    console.log(`  ${ind}`);
  }
  if (!has) console.log(`  <none>`);
}
```

And don't forget that it's very easy to get an Array of results from a generator; you just need to do:

```
let resultsArr = [ ...getAdjacentDupIndices([ 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3 ]) ];
```

Comment: this seems to only give `[3]` and not `[4]`  I would need the response to show `arr[3]` and `arr[4]` or wherever the adjacent pair happen to fall.

Comment: Edited; although if this is anything other than a homework question I recommend you stick with only returning the first index for adjacent duplicate values; the second index is completely redundant

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, here is an example of collecting indexes of adjacent duplicates and using this collection to change the corresponding elements:

```js
const array = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1];
console.log(array.join(' '));

const dupIndexes = new Set();

for (let i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
  if (array[i] === array[i + 1]) dupIndexes.add(i).add(i + 1);
}

console.log(...dupIndexes);

for (const i of dupIndexes) {
  array[i] = '-';
}

console.log(array.join(' '));
```